# css transitions not firing smoothly

Tags: javascript, css, transition

code:
js:

```
function showservices() {
    document.getElementById("market").style.transition="height 3s ease-in";
    document.getElementById("market").style.height="0px";
    document.getElementById("market_").style.transition="height 3s ease-in";
    document.getElementById("market_").style.height="auto";
}
```

html: (I call the function from chrome console, and also tried with a buton)

```
<div id="market">Hello</div>
<div id="market_">Good Bye</div>
```

It goes on but not smoothly, transition not working.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Any console errors? Testing in a CSS3-friendly browser?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You only need .style.transition="height 3s ease-in"; once

Comment: @frenchie It is actually changing two different elements so it is needed

Comment: @ZachSaucier: yes, just saw that, you're right. One element is called "market" and the other element is called "market_". Not the best choice of IDs IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot animate to a height of `auto`. You have to calculate that height, perhaps by placing it offscreen and using `clientHeight` or the appropriate measurement, save it to a variable, and toggle it using that variable

```
var market = document.getElementById("market"),
    market_ = document.getElementById("market_"),
    // Save the heights
    marketHeight = market.clientHeight,
    market_Height = market_.clientHeight;

// Remove the height of market_
market_.style.height = "0px";

function showservices() {
    market.style.transition="height 3s ease-in";
    market_.style.transition="height 3s ease-in";
    market.style.height = "0px";
    // In essence animates to the "auto" value, but is an actual pixel value
    market_.style.height = market_Height + "px";
}
showservices();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F86Ka/)

Note: If the height of the toggled variable varies on widow resize then you will have to calculate its height each time, likely within a `window.onresize` function

Comment: you're awesome guy, thank you, never thought to see things as clearly!":"